# Outlook 13 Missing Emails on HP Windows 7 desktop computer

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2013

Just installed Outlook 13 and my problem is that some emails in Outlook 13 are not showing under All emails but do show up during search mode if you know name of sender.

Missing emails were present yesterday but not today. Missing emails are present on my Blackberry cell phone under same email address as Outlook 13. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you don't have any view filters turned on.

You can check for them (and clear them) via:

- In the left column, select **Inbox**.
- Select the **View** tab.
- In the **Current View** group, click the **View Settings** button.
- Click the **Filter...** button.

If you want to clear them:

- Click the **Clear All** button.